# Who is the composer of the soundtrack of the movie Incubus (1966)?

Tags: soundtrack, incubus

Who is the composer of the soundtrack of the movie Incubus (1966)? I searched, but I did not find his the name.

[IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0059311/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, the compopser of *Incubus* was *The Outer Limits* composer [Dominic Frontiere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominic_Frontiere#Selected_works). The music editor was [John Caper Jr](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0135092/). This is corroborated [here](http://web.mit.edu/esperanto/www/incubus.html) and [in this TCM page](http://www.tcm.com/underground/article.html?oid=258907), that also suggests that the score was recycled from *Outer Limits* episodes.

Comment: Thank you. So, the original soundtrack is from _Outer Limits_?

Comment: Various online sources seem to suggest that, yes. [One of them](http://www.filmscoremonthly.com/board/posts.cfm?threadID=16729&forumID=1&archive=1) specifically mentions an episode called [Nightmare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightmare_%281963_The_Outer_Limits%29).